# How to copy selected text Python

Tags: python, pynput

Im used pynput library for press keys and add text to the active window, it's works:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press('a')
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
```

But i cant execute combinations ctrl+c or ctrl+v

Answer (score 3):

you can use the keyboard module instead:

it can be installed with:

```
pip install keyboard
```

here is the code if you want to use it:

```
import keyboard,time
print("Select text you want to copy...")
time.sleep(1)

keyboard.press("ctrl+c")
print("ctr+c pressed...")
print("go to a place you would like to paste on")

time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press("ctrl+v")
print("ctrl-v successfully pressed...")
print("Program finished with status 0\nPress enter to exit...",end='')
input()
```

Comment: ctrl + c not works(

Comment: for me it works... strange

Comment: just for me script don't copy text, but enter text with ctrl + v hmmmm

Comment: when the program runs it gives you 1 second to select the text, and 1 second to go to the page you want to paste into.

Comment: im understand that,ctrl + c combination not works for me, thank you maybe your answer will help someone